# Android: how to save image to cache dir?

Tags: android

I have the code as this:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        //create name based on time? just a simple link to photo
        //save to cache file
        File file = getExternalCacheDir();
        if (file != null) {
            try {
                String root = file.getAbsolutePath();
                File imageFile = new File(file, "m_images.jpeg");
                boolean tr = imageFile.mkdirs();
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                boolean complete = image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
                if (!complete) {
                    Log.d("tag", "image doesn't saved");
                }
                Log.d("tag", "image saved");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("tag", "Can't save image", e);
            }
```

But I always get this exception when I open FileOoutputStream:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.whatever/cache/m_images.jpeg (Is a directory)
```

Could you say where is the cause of this issue? Why file doesn't create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.whatever/cache/m_images.jpeg (Is a directory)`
 means it's a directory. It would be execute well when remove the line `boolean tr = imageFile.mkdirs();`